# Edit Prestashop current orders view

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.0.9.

I wish to edit the raw HTML for this part.

[image]

Full size image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hazQp.png

I wish to add an extra colum to the filters but I can't actually find the code for it...

I have searched through the `adminXXXX/themes/default/template/` directory. Specifically the orders files but they only seem to be relevant for the view you get when you actually click on one of the orders listed below. (Below meaning the orders below the filters that you can't see)

Does anyone know the actual location for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filters for BO orders are created by `controllers\admin\AdminOrdersController.php`.

In order to preserve prestashop core code it's indicated you create an override for this controller, where you'll need to join the table that you need (if not already joined), specify where in your table is the field you want to use for filter and also the field itself. Have a closer look at the constructor function of *AdminOrdersController* to better understand how to do this.

For example if you want to add the carrier name as a filter, create `override\controllers\admin\AdminOrdersController.php` file and add the following code:

```
<?php

class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_join .= 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'carrier` cr ON (cr.`id_carrier` = a.`id_carrier`)';
        $this->_select .= ', cr.name as carrier';
        $this->fields_list['carrier'] = array(
            'title' => $this->l('Carrier'),
            'align' => 'text-center'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I see! Now in the orginal controller, it uses the `_orders` table. I'm wanting to have a filter based on which carrier they've used for their order... The carriers are within a different table. How could I do that?

Comment: That's great but it throws an error.
`Bad SQL query
Unknown column 'carrier' in 'where clause'`

Comment: So I changed the code to order_carrier as that's what I think you were aiming for. Now another error is thrown... `Unknown column 'cr.name' in 'field list'`

Comment: The table that you need is `ps_carrier` to get the name, because you already have the `id_carrier` in `ps_orders` and in `_select` `as carrier` is important because in table there is no column named _carrier_. I've tested this on my localhost and it's working. I think you could also use the `ps_orders_carrier` by joining this table to match `id_order`, then you'll still need `ps_carrier` to get the name, but this only complicates the code to do the same thing.

Comment: What effect should I see after adding this file? Nothing changed for me... I'm using PS 1.6.0.8 without caching

Comment: @van_folmert in `BO > Orders > Orders` you should see a column `Carrier` that can be used to sort your orders.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like column with carrier
add this (behind: "$this->_join = '"):

```
    LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'carrier ca ON (ca.id_carrier = a.id_carrier)
```

and to field list (behind "$this->fields_list = array(") add this:

```
'carrier' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Carrier'),
            'align' => 'text-center',            
            'filter_key' => 'ca!name'
   ),
```