# Filter by carrier in prestashop orders view

Tags: php, html, sql, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I'm using prestashop 1.6.1.4.

I want to add a column named "Carrier" at the orders view and a selection box at the top to be filtered by the selected carrier.

The closest answer I found was this one:
[Edit Prestashop current orders view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862651/edit-prestashop-current-orders-view)

It works fine to show a carrier column but:

1. It shows a text box in the top to filter (its not bad but will be
   better a selection box)
2. If you write something in that box and you press search, it
   throws the following error:

> Bad SQL query Unknown column 'carrier' in 'where clause'

I assume that the code adds a `WHERE 'carrier' like %***%` which is wrong because "carrier " is an alias from a join.

The problem is that I don't know how to modify the code to solve it, I dove into prestashop documentation but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Has this been solved? I am facing the same problem.