# Prestashop 1.7 add new column to orders table

Tags: module, controller, prestashop

Good day all.
I'm doing a little module that should display a new column into the order table in backend.

I've done this:

in my module, I've done a new file into `my_module/controllers/admin/AdminOrderController.php`

in that file, I've written:

```
class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{

    public function __construct()
    {
 print_r("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"); 
    }
}
```

but once I go to the order list...nothing happens.
(I've deleted the calls_index.php from var/cache/).
what I'm doing wrong?
Can you help me understand what I hae to do in order to add a new column to that table?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685142/prestashop-1-6-create-module-to-display-carrier-filter/46693440#46693440

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override is not recommended. you should try not to use override on your modules.

You have to use PrestaShop dynamic hooks:

```
public function hookActionAdminOrdersListingFieldsModifier($params)
{
    $params['fields']['your_new_field'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('label'),
        'align' => 'center',
    );
}
```

Also you can modify admin forms:

```
public function hookActionAdminOrdersFormModifier($params)
{
    dd($params);
}
```

Comment: oh, that's interesting, I guess it's exactly what I was searching for. tanks, I' take a look at it asap.

Comment: very very interesting, thanks, may I ask you where you have found those informations? Prestashop is nice, but the lack of any coherent documentation is a very big obstacle.

Comment: These are new hook which were added into PrestaShop 1.6, but since they  were not mentioned in the documents, most developer used to use old hooks and they don't use these new features. How they know that? Well we're official PrestaShop partner in Iran and we develop it for Iranian users :)

Answer (score 1):

The correct folder to create an admin controller override with a module is:

`/my_module/override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php`

if you change it in your module, reinstall it and the file should be placed properly and the `print_r` should appear.

Comment: followed it but nothing happens...
just to check, once "reinstalled" the override should be copied into ROOT/override/admin/
right?

Comment: After the reinstall, the file must be in: `ROOT/override/controllers/admin`

Now, we have checked and the name of the override file is not correct, must be `AdminOrdersController.php`:

`/my_module/override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php`